# Case when Parent SpecID is Same as Child SpecID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know record where ParentSpecID = to ChildSpecID cannot think of how to approach

[image: 1]

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very simple using `inner join`, if I followed you correctly.

```
Select p.*, c.*
  From parentspecid p
  Join itemspecfullstruc i on i.rootitemspecid = p.itemspecid
  Join childspecid c on i.childitemspecid = c.itemspecid
 Where p.itemspecid = c.itemspecid
```